# Unable to display data from the List of Films in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on `react-router-dom@6.8` and fetching data using `useEffect` hook and updated data with `useState` hook.
My routes are in `Main` component and nested route of `"/films"` which have film details is in `Films` component. I have attached the screenshot in which I am just able to access the specific id of films but not displaying film detail. `Film` is accessed via props in `Films` using method `findFilms`.

Main.js

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Films } from '../Films/Films'
import { Home } from '../Home/Home'

export const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='mainContent'>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/films/*" element={<Films />}></Route>
        <Route path="/planets/*" element={<Planets />}></Route>
        <Route path="/people" element={<People list={people} />}>
          <Route path=":id" element={<Person list={people} />}></Route>
          {/* Person is passed prop with fetch results */}
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Home />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Films.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Film } from '../Film/Film'
import './films.css'

export const Films = (props) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (function getFilms() {
      let url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/';
      fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => {
          if (!resp.ok) throw new Error(resp.statusText);
          return resp.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setList(data.results);
        })
        .catch(console.warn);
    })();
  }, []);

  function findFilm(id) {
    return list.find((item, index) => parseInt(id) === index + 1);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="results">
        <h2>Film List</h2>

        {list.length === 0 && <p>No films...</p>}
        {list.map((film, index) => (
          <p key={film.title}>
            <NavLink to={`/films/${index + 1}`} className={({isActive}) => (isActive ? "activeLink" : 'none')}>
              {film.title}
            </NavLink>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="details">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/films/:id" element={<Film findFilm={findFilm} />} />
        </Routes>  
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Film.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react'

export const Film = ({ findFilm }) => {
  const [film, setFilm] = useState(null);
  const { id } = useParams();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setFilm(findFilm(id));
  }, [findFilm, id]);

  let details = (
    <>
      <p>{film && film.title}</p>
      <p>{film && film.release_date}</p>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Film Details</h2>
      {film && details}
    </>
  )
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/App/App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`Main` component is being rendered in `App` component. Please look in the code either I will have to make css file className results to display data or it's a routing problem why code is not able to display data in the page planet is sub component of Planet.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested `Routes` components build their routes ***relative*** to the parent `Route` component. If the `Films` component is rendered on `path="/films/*"` then all descendent routes will be relative from `"/films"`. A descendent route `path="/films/:id"` resolves to `"/films/films/:id"` which probably ***not*** what you intended.

Remove the leading `"/films"` segment of the descendent routes.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/:id" element={<Film findFilm={findFilm} />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you Drew Reese, after removing it I am able to access it. Thank you.

Comment: plz recheck this path regarding router v6.8

Comment: <Route path="/people" element={<People list={people} />}>
        
          <Route path=":id" element={<Person list={people} />}></Route>
            
            {/* Person is passed prop with fetch results */}
          </Route>

Comment: @IramKahkashan Those two routes appear fine to me. Is there an issue or concern with them?

Comment: Facing same issue using this method accessing id on url but not is displaying data.

Comment: @IramKahkashan These are ***nested*** routes (*as opposed to **descendent** routes*) so the parent `People` component needs to render an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) for the nested routes to render their `element` content into. See [Outlets in Main Concepts](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) as well. If you need more in-depth help then it might be better to create a new SO post specific to this other issue that includes these routes and the `People` and `Person` component code.

Comment: <Route path="/people" element={<People list={people} />}>
        
          <Route path="/people/:id" element={<Person list={people} />}/>
            
            {/* Person is passed prop with fetch results */}
          </Route>    Using this data is not displaying just accessing url but if we remove parent from child Route is displays nothing except white page.(":id")